# In a Svelte readable store array, How can I update only one item without touching the others?

Tags: javascript, arrays, store, svelte

I guess this question is more on JS sysntax, but I have a store array like this:

```
export const store = readable( {id: 0, value: 0} , set => {
    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:65432");
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        set({id: 0, value: data});
    }
})
```

The store defines its set method to update the value from a websockets connection.
How can I do the same but with a store array? Something like:

```
arr = [];
for(i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++) {
    arr = [...arr,{id: i, value: 0}];
}

export const store = readable( [{arr}] , set => {
    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:65432");
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var channel = data.channel;
        set({id: data.channel, value: data.value});
    }
})
```

Here is where I dont manage to "set" o the array, and without having to declare the whole array every update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case what you want to save in the store is not an array, but an object, it would make easier this step. Something like:

```
export const store = readable({} , set => {
    let channels = {};
    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:65432");
    socket.onmessage = function ({data}) {
        let { channel, value } = JSON.parse(data);

        // update `channels`
        channels = {...channels, [channel]: value };

        // set the new `channels` as store value
        set(channels)
    }
})
```

Notice that in this way you will have directly the channel as key of the object: so if a channel already exists, it will be updated instead of added. And if it doesn't exists, it will be added.

In your subscriber you can therefore have something like:

```
store.subscribe(channels => {
  for (let [channel, value] of Object.entries(channels)) {
    console.log(`channel ${channel} received ${value}`);
  }
});
```

As final note, consider that this code creates a new object every update to avoid side effect, that's common practice.
However, if you have a lot of data in the object and you're aware of the possible implication, you could just add / update the single key without duplicating the object every time, for performance / memory reason.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's very nice approach for my purpose, except that by doing it with arrays instead, I could create something like ``` {#each $channelArray as item} ...and here put some component, each one reactive to one of the channels (items in the array)```

Comment: But you can still do it, just as I shown for `store.subscribe` you can use in the template the same logic. So using `#each Object.entries($store) as [channel, value]` or `#each Object.values($store) as value` (if you're just interested in the values).

Comment: Perfect! And what if instead of a flat dictionary Key:value I would also like to attach channel: {value, lastupdate} ? Another concern is that, with your approach I'm trying to set the readable with an initial set of channels, but the App doesn't seem to see them when importing the readable (or might I be doing something wrong...)

Comment: The value of the object can be anything, so you can also have nested object such as `channels = {...channels, [channel]: { value, timestamp: Date.now() } };` for example. Also, as you declare `channels = {}` you can set a non empty object such as `channels = { "1": {value: "foo", timestamp: Date.now() } }` (or more than one). But this is just vanilla js.

Answer (score 1):

I think a readable store won't solve your problem, because you don't have an update method here. Why don't you try a [writable store](https://svelte.dev/docs#writable) instead? It gives you an update function with the current value as an argument, so you can do something like this:

```
    let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:65432");
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      var channel = data.channel;
      store.update(n => [...n, { id: data.channel, value: data.value }]);
    };
```

Here is a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a785776811f4236ab0a80d7c486724d?version=3.23.0) with an example of how it works. It uses intervals to simulate the webhooks functionality. If you open the console, you can see the updated store value.

Comment: Ok then, so update method from a writable would be the way to go.

Comment: In my humble opinion, yes. If it works, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the actual value of the readable store also inside the callback. Then you can update the existing array without replacing all:

```
<script>
    import {readable} from 'svelte/store'

    let intervalHandle
    const arr = new readable(['Start'], (set) => {
        intervalHandle = setInterval(() => {
            set([...$arr, 'Another value'])     
        }, 1000)
    })

</script>

<h1>Readable demo</h1>
<button on:click={() => clearInterval(intervalHandle)}>Stop it</button>
{#each $arr as item}
<div>{item}</div>
{/each}
```

Comment: But this would update the array by adding a new item every time right?

Comment: This simple example just shows *how* you can update an array (or an object, works the same) of a readable store. You take the existing one, modify as you like and set the updated version. The store will call it's subscribers callbacks and thy know that "something" has changed - but not, what. The store can't tell that the item at index x or the value for key Foo has changed.